# Lee-Strazizich's unit root test - ur.ls function - error

Tags: time-series, breakpoints

I am trying to run the ur.ls() function written by https://github.com/hannes101 and https://stackoverflow.com/users/5795592/hannes101 to estimate the Lee-Strazizich's unit root tests, but I get the following error message:

Error in if (print.results == "print") { : the condition has length > 1

Any suggestions about how to solve this?

Many thanks

I mentioned an error I get whenever I run a function contributed by one developer, and I am expecting suggestions and recommendations about how to solve the situation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.